# Функция sscanf не распознает шестнадцатеричное число, INF и NAN

Tags: c

Имеется следующий код:

```
char string[] = "0xa.1fp10";    
double num;    
sscanf(string, "%lf", &num);    
printf("%lf\n", num);
```

По идее ответ должен быть 10364.0, но программа выдает 0.0. Также sscanf не распознает INF и NAN:

```
sscanf("inf", "%lf", &num);

sscanf("nan", "%lf", &num);
```

В чем причина?

Comment: `%f` распознает только десятичную запись. Для hex используйте [strtod](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)

Comment: стандарт : "Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity, or NaN, whose format is
the same as expected for the subject sequence of the **strtod** function." @avp

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос недостаточно информации. Покажите минимальный компилируемый пример, который демонстрирует ваше мнение. Оборудование (планшет/пк). Версию операционной системы. Версию компилятора. Какими командами вы запускаете компиляцию. В какой кодировке находиться ваш пример (KOI/CP1251/UTF-8/UTF-16).